# Issues downloading and installing ubuntu iso alongside win7

Tags: installation, dual-boot, usb, iso

When downloading the iso it downloads normally for awhile displaying that i have a few hours to wait and then randomly jumps to complete. Upon attempting to burn the iso to USB to install the pendrive program claims numerous file errors and then completes the format of my usb. when i attempt to boot from the usb during post it either comes up with nothing and forces me to reboot my laptop or comes up that i'm missing files and that the boot cannot continue. can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?
  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
  Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at
  http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a browser error. Its happened to me as well.
The iso download is corrupted (missing files)
I just go to my browser options and clean out all the history,etc
then close and reopen the browser. That has always cleared up the problem.
Also I find that I much prefer Unetbootin for burning the iso to
a flash drive. Just point it to the iso and check that it has properly
identified your usb and you are good to go. You can get Unetbootin
from the software manager
Oh, if you are running a slow computer then try to just let the iso download,
don't open other pages, etc while it is downloading!
Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

To check if your Download was complete and no errors occurred, you can compare the [MD5 checksum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows) of the downloaded file with the checksum computed for the file on the server, as displayed in the official [checksum list](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes). If the MD5sum is different, something went wrong with your download and you should redownload the ISO.

If for some reason your downloads keep failing and you think it's the servers fault or a bad undersea cable, you can instead use a different mirror (see the [list of CD-image mirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors)).

If the download keeps failing and you suspect that your own internet connection is not stable, (and you don't mind giving some bandwidth for upload,) you can use [bittorrent](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) downloads. Bittorrent has error detection for partial downloads [citation needed] and therefore automatically redownloads faulty blocks before marking a download as finished.